# How to replace everything but letters and numbers in pandas column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df like so:

```
id    answer
1      how are you? 
2      What's the word in the letters'
3      .... \xa0 \xa0' Hey what's up?
```

How do I replace every thing that is not a letter or number with nothing in df.answer?

New df will look like this:

```
id    question
1      how are you 
2      Whats the word in the letters
3      Hey whats up
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.answer = df.apply(lambda row: ''.join(i for i in row.answer if i.isalnum() or i==' '), axis=1)
```

This should work.

Comment: How does this get rid of "Quest1" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module:

```
df['answer'] = df['words'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+&\s','',x))
```

Another alternative:

```
df['words'].str.replace(r'\W+&\s', '')
```

Comment: Instead of using `apply` and a `lambda` - why not use the same expression using `df['words'].str.replace('regex here')` ?